vim: strange behaviour of keys F1 ... F5
I have noticed a strange behaviour of Vim that does not correspond to what I read online. For example the <F1> key inserts a ‘P’ in the line above, <F2> a Q, <F3> an R, <F4> an S and <F5> toggles the case.
I tried running:
vi -u NONE text

but I still get the same behaviour.  If I run:
:verbose map <F1>

I get:
No mapping found

What could it be?
# LANG=C aptitude search ~i~nvim
i   vim                                                                             2:9.1.0861-1   - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor                                                          
i   vim-common                                                                      2:9.1.0861-1   - Vi IMproved - Common files                                                                
i A vim-nox                                                                         2:9.1.0861-1   - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with scripting languages support                       
i A vim-runtime                                                                     2:9.1.0861-1   - Vi IMproved - Runtime files                                                               
i A vim-tiny                                                                        2:9.1.0861-1   - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version                                        


I did as suggested by romainl. Inside Vim:
^[OP^[OQ^[OR^[OS^[[15~

On my terminal (xfce4-terminal):
^[OP^[OQ^[OR^[OS^[[15~

I, too, have the feeling that it has nothing to do with Vim but is some setting that I recently changed. The problem is that I don't know where to look.

What do you expect F-keys to do? They do nothing by default in Vim. Can you map them to something? What terminal emulator do you use? Could that cause the behavior? Have you tested if you get the same behavior in other applications? Anyway, this sounds like it should be a bug report (not sure for whom... Debian perhaps) instead of a question on SO.

Probably unrelated but do install one of the "huge" Vim versions, e.g. vim-gtk3. Debian has a long standing tradition of saving you some megabytes of hard drive space in exchange for a bag of missing features.


Start Vim with $ vim -Nu NONE. 2. Go into insert mode with i. 3. Press Ctrl+V, then <F1>. 4. repeat for the other keys. 5. Add the content of the buffer to your question. 6. Do the same in your shell and add the output to your question. Working hypothesis: it has nothing to do with Vim.


@romainl I updated my post with the information you requested. Thanks.

@devnull let's keep it. But you should post an answer and accept it. FWIW, the linux terminal definition is very "primitive" and plenty of complex TUI apps have problems with it. If you can recall the reason of that choice that will make this QA even more useful.

I managed to arrive at the solution when I tried to use vim with another user (root or a new one). The problem did not occur even though the ~/.vim folder was a symlink to that of the main user. In the end, the problem was that I had put this in my .bashrc file:
export TERM=linux

Removing it solved the problem.
The reason I had entered this parameter in .bashrc was because I noticed a strange behaviour in vim: in INSERT mode, pressing the ESC key and then an arrow key would insert the letters A, B, C or D, depending on the arrow key. As I use this key combination practically all the time when editing a file with vim, this was quite annoying.
Investigating further, I discovered that the reason why this was happening was due to this vim plugin:
tmsvg/pear-tree

To cut it short by setting this parameter:
" Automatically map <BS>, <CR>, and <Esc>
let g:pear_tree_map_special_keys = 0 

in ~/.vim/plugin/pear-tree.vim solves the issue.
